# Python: abstract instance variable?

Tags: python, abstract-class, python-3.6, instance-variables

Is there a way to declare an abstract instance variable for a class in python?

For example, we have an abstract base class, `Bird`, with an abstract method `fly` implemented using the `abc` package, and the abstract instance variable `feathers` (what I'm looking for) implemented as a property.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Bird(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def feathers(self):
        """The bird's feathers."""

    @abstractmethod
    def fly(self):
        """Take flight."""
```

The problem is that `Eagle`, a class derived from `Bird`, is required to have `feathers` implemented as a property method. So the following is not an acceptable class, but I'd like it to be

```
class Eagle(Bird):

    def __init__(self):
        self.feathers = 'quill'

    def fly(self):
        print('boy are my arms tired')
```

There might be a problem since the requirement is on the instance itself, and really after its instantiation, so I don't know if things like the `abc` package will still work.

Are there some standard ways of handling this?

Comment: Maybe I missed the point. Can you shortly explain why do you need an abstract property? Otherwise just let it be a normal property.

Comment: I'd like it to be enforced, so that if Eagle instances don't have a `feathers` attribute, a helpful error is raised (to avoid unpredictable behavior). (If you meant more specifically, sorry but it's hard to answer, since I was hoping to use this for several different variables.)

Answer (score 11):

The `abc` system doesn't include a way to declare an abstract instance variable. The code that determines whether a class is concrete or abstract has to run before any instances exist; it can inspect a class for methods and properties easily enough, but it has no way to tell whether instances *would* have any particular instance attribute.

The closest thing is probably a variable annotation:

```
class Bird(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    feathers : str
    ...
```

`abc` won't do anything with that annotation, but it at least expresses to readers and static type checkers that instances of `Bird` are supposed to have a `feathers` instance variable. (Whether static type checkers will understand that this instance variable is supposed to come from subclasses, I don't know.)

Answer (score 10):

Something simple like the following can work, using a common property:

```
class Bird(object):
    @property
    def feathers(self):
        try:
            return self._feathers
        except AttributeError:
            raise WhateverError('No feathers')  # maybe obfuscate inner structure

class Eagle(Bird):
    def __init__(self):
        self._feathers = 'quill'

>>> Bird().feathers
WhateverError: No feathers
>>> Eagle().feathers
'quill'
```

Comment: I would add that `Bird._init__` should make the actual assignment, and that `Eagle.__init__` should simply call `super().__init__('quill')` to provide the value for the assignment. `_feathers` is an implementation detail of the property defined by `Bird`.